# Alternate traffic through multiple interfaces on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I have a VPS with three IP's. I am trying to setup the network configuration to allow round robin usage of the three IP's for outgoing requests (downloads into VPS). How do I change the following configuration to effect that? Thanks!

```
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2894 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8784773 (8.7 MB)  TX bytes:286703 (286.7 KB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:144.21.164.150  P-t-P:184.22.194.150  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:144.21.164.157  P-t-P:184.22.194.157  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:2  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:144.21.164.156  P-t-P:184.22.194.156  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you want round-robin use of the IP addresses? Because it would seem to make a lot more sense to want round-robin use of the interfaces. (Note that the local source IP address, interface outbound packets are sent on, and interface inbound packets are received on are three different things.) It would help a lot if you explained your outer problem. (Since it's not clear what your proposed solution would solve.)

Comment: I have multiple internet connections and am trying to split bandwidth equally across all of these. I did come across some documentation to enable network interface bonding using a round robin policy. However, I have come to understand that traffic distribution might be uneven due to caching of routes. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest DNS round-robin. You do not need to alter your interfaces, simply put your virtual interface IPs in the zone file.

There is a simple configuration guide [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-setup-round-robin-dns/).